# Pass a pointer by const reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Is passing a pointer by const reference not done for optimization?

Ex.

```
bool testHelper(const TreeNode*& p, const TreeNode*& q) {
    return false;
}

TreeNode* test(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
    recursiveHelper(p, q);
}
```

Error:

```
Line 17: Char 28: error: binding reference of type 'const TreeNode *' to value of type 'TreeNode *' not permitted due to incompatible qualifiers
                testHelper(p, q);
                           ^
Line 12: Char 42: note: passing argument to parameter 'p' here
        bool testHelper(const TreeNode*& p, const TreeNode*& q) {
                                         ^
```

Comment: First question: Why a pointer in the first place? Second question: What do you gain by passing a trivial to copy value like a pointer as a reference?

Comment: `bool testHelper(const TreeNode* const& p, const TreeNode* const& q)` would be passing it by `const` reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is passing a pointer by const reference not done for optimization?

No, it isn't, because it isn't any faster. The added indirection is potentially slower.

> ```
> bool testHelper(const TreeNode*& p, const TreeNode*& q)
> ```

Those are not references to const. Those are references to non-const pointers to const.

---

Other bugs:

- `test` was declared to return non-void but lacks a return statement
- You haven't declared the function `recursiveHelper` that you call.